# Why does Pillow Python invert the color of a CMYK image when converting it to PDF

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-imaging-library

I'm testing a simple script as shown below to convert JPG to PDF, but somehow the output PDF comes out inverted. The same behaviour is not seen when I convert the image to 'RGB' before saving it as PDF. The original image is in 'CMYK'. How can I avoid this?

Sample code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

image = Image.open('door.jpg')
image.save(
  'output.pdf',
  resolution=180.0,
  quality=100
)
```

Input and output images:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a limitation in Pillow Python and will be fixed in the latest release (v7.2.^) - https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4860

Answer (score 0):

If the image is known to be CMYK, try converting it to RGB before saving.

```
cmyk = Image.open('door.jpg')
rgb = cmyk.convert("RGB")
rgb.save(...)
```

Comment: I think you missed that part in the OP, i've mentioned that it does work with RGB. But I need CMYK, as it's meant to be printed and not for web.

Comment: I did miss that. If it's meant to be printed, and the intent is to get it in to a PDF first, you're at the mercy of how (or whether) Pillow supports putting a CMYK image into a PDF. The [documention](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#pdf) is silent on that.

Comment: The document is certainly limited. I'll try raising the issue in Github, as its either a limitation in Pil or undocumented